When updating to xcode 15 flutter project shows 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found error
When updating to xcode 15, my flutter project which is in version ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0" forced me to use minimum iOS 12, there are some libraries that present this error.

The project needed to run to be able to upload updates
